# PyTorch: Is it possible to differentiate a matrix?

Tags: python, pytorch, differentiation

How do you differentiate a matrix in PyTorch? I have tried the following but neither work:

Instance 1:

```
a = torch.tensor([1., 2, 3], requires_grad=True)
b = torch.tensor([4., 5, 6], requires_grad=True) 
c = a*b
c.backward()
#print(b.grad)

>>> RuntimeError: grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs
```

Instance 2:

```
a = torch.tensor([1., 2, 3], requires_grad=True)
b = torch.tensor([4., 5, 6], requires_grad=True)

c = a*b
print(b.grad)

>>> None
```

Answer (score 7):

It is possible but it doesn't really fit into the standard use case of PyTorch where you are generally interested in the gradient of a scalar valued function.

The derivative of a matrix Y w.r.t. a matrix X can be represented as a Generalized Jacobian. For the case where both matrices are just vectors this reduces to the standard [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant), where each row of the Jacobian is the transpose of the gradient of one element of Y with respect to X. More generally if X is shape (n1, n2, ..., nD) and Y is shape (m1, m2, ..., mE) then a natural way to represent the Generalized Jacobian of Y with respect to X is as a tensor of shape (m1, m2, ..., mE, n1, n2, ..., nD).

There are two ways to compute the Generalized Jacobian that I'm aware of in PyTorch.

### Option 1

Repeated application of back-propagation on each element of Y.

```py
import torch

def construct_jacobian(y, x, retain_graph=False):
    x_grads = []
    for idx, y_element in enumerate(y.flatten()):
        if x.grad is not None:
            x.grad.zero_()
        # if specified set retain_graph=False on last iteration to clean up
        y_element.backward(retain_graph=retain_graph or idx < y.numel() - 1)
        x_grads.append(x.grad.clone())
    return torch.stack(x_grads).reshape(*y.shape, *x.shape)
```

then the Jacobian for your test case may be computed using

```py
a = torch.tensor([1., 2., 3.])
b = torch.tensor([4., 5., 6.], requires_grad=True)
c = a * b

jacobian = construct_jacobian(c, b)

print(jacobian)
```

which results in

```py
tensor([[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 2., 0.],
        [0., 0., 3.]])
```

### Option 2

In PyTorch 1.5.1 a new autograd.functional API was introduced, including the new function [`torch.autograd.functional.jacobian`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.functional.jacobian). This produces the same results as the previous example but takes a function as an argument. Not demonstrated here, but you can provide the `jacobian` function a list of inputs if your function takes multiple independent tensors as input. In that case the `jacobian` would return a tuple containing the Generalized Jacobian for each of the input arguments.

```py
import torch

a = torch.tensor([1., 2., 3.])

def my_fun(b):
    return a * b

b = torch.tensor([4., 5., 6.], requires_grad=True)

jacobian = torch.autograd.functional.jacobian(my_fun, b)

print(jacobian)
```

which also produces

```py
tensor([[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 2., 0.],
        [0., 0., 3.]])
```

---

As an aside, in some literature the term "gradient" is used to refer to the transpose of the Jacobian matrix. If that's what you're after then, assuming Y and X are vectors, you can simply use the code above and take the transpose of the resulting Jacobian matrix. If Y or X are higher order tensors (matrices or n-dimensional tensors) then I'm not aware of any literature that distinguishes between gradient and Generalized Jacobian. A natural way to represent such a "transpose" of the Generalized Jacobian would be to use `Tensor.permute` to turn it into a tensor of shape (n1, n2, ..., nD, m1, m2, ..., mE).

---

As another aside, the concept of the Generalized Jacobian is rarely used in literature ([example usage](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/handouts/derivatives.pdf)) but is actually relatively useful in practice. This is because it basically works as a bookkeeping technique to keep track of the original dimensionality of Y and X. By this I mean you could just as easily take Y and X and flatten them into vectors, regardless of their original shape. Then the derivative would be a standard Jacobian matrix. Consequently this Jacobian matrix would be equivalent to a reshaped version of the Generalized Jacobian.